# Compare a String to the ID of a array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, compare

So I'm trying to find the details for a particular item in one array from a different array:

```
foreach($json_items['result']['items'] as $item)
{ 
    foreach($items_all['items_game']['items'] as $schemaItem)
    {

      echo $Schema[$item['defindex']];
        if($item['defindex'] == $Schema[$item['defindex']])
        {
          echo "works";
            echo $schemaItem['name'].'<br />';
          break;
        } else {
          //echo "not";
        }
    }
}
```

`defindex` is a unqiue ID for the item, `Schema` is a database type array of item info

but `Schema` is designed like this:

```
 [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Anti-Mage's Glaive
        [prefab] => default_item
```

So `1` here would be the `defindex` for this item in the `Schema` array

What can I do so  can compare them and get out the info such as name and prefab for the item? Thanks.

Comment: i added the whole loop, i didnt understand comment.. what i wanna achieve is compare my $item['defindex'] which is say 1500 to the id of the array in my Schema array, but this $Schema[$item['defindex']]) returns an array and not a string. And if and only if both match i wanna dislpay the contents of that array.

Answer (score 0):

Is this inside of a loop through the array?  If so, you could try:

```
foreach ($item as $key => $value){
    // Do compare here, $key would be the array index $value the value.
}
```

Comment: i added the whole loop, i didnt understand comment.. 

what i wanna achieve is compare my $item['defindex'] which is say 1500 to the id of the array in my Schema array, but this $Schema[$item['defindex']]) returns an array and not a string.

And if and only if both match i wanna dislpay the contents of that array.

Comment: Apologies.  I've never worked with the $Schema variable before.

I read the question as you needed to be able to have the variable value and it's variable name available.

Answer (score 0):

You could access the array in `$Schema`

```
$item = $Schema[$item['defindex']];
$item_name = $item['name'];
$item_prefab = $item['prefab'];
```